# WC Booking query bookings with date ranges

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, query, rest-api

Using [WooCommerce Bookings](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/) extension and the newly provided REST API I search a way to query bookings by date intervals.

Is possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Third-party plugins are generally off-topic according to the site guidelines, please take a closer look at the [help] to get familiar with them. You should ask this question directly to WooCommerce, after all you paid good money for the extension, and specifically the support.

Comment: Ok I understand! While I'm working for a client I will try to get access to support